# Superscript letters without decimal using inline style

Tags: css, html

I am looking for a way to create an ordered list with superscript letters with no decimal point. I need to write it using inline styling. Not the best method I do realize, but those are my limitations that I have to work with.

My current code for superscript letters in my documents looks like this:

```
<span style="font-size: 0.8em; position:relative; bottom:0.3em">
```

I am unable to use any `:before` pseudoclass.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You can't use `:before`or you it doesn't  work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<sup>` tag. The [`<sup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) tag was made specifically to style superscript text.